# GWT UiHandler on HTMLPanel

Tags: gwt, event-handling, uibinder

I'm writing a widget with the following markup:

```
<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="shortcutPanel" styleName="{style.shortcut}">
    <g:Image ui:field="shortcutImage"></g:Image>
    <span ui:field="shortcutLabel"></span>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

So essentially a div that wraps and image and a label.  Now, instead of adding the event handlers on the image/span, I'd like an onClick to be associated with the HTMLPanel.  My problem however is that gwt tells me that

> shortcutPanel doesn't not have an addClickHandler method associated

So I'm assuming the difference is that HTMLPanel doesn't implement `HasClickHandlers` or something along that line.  I'm wondering then what is the standard way to attach a click handler to a Ui element such as an HTMLPanel or even better, is there such a GWT Widget that is essentially a div wrapper that I can easily attach events to with the @UiHandler annotation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`FocusPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusPanel.html) - it has all the goodies: `HasAllFocusHandlers`, `HasAllKeyHandlers`, `HasAllMouseHandlers`, `HasBlurHandlers`, **`HasClickHandlers`**.... to name *a few* :) I find it to be the easiest and best way to attach click handlers to a Panel.

Comment: That worked Thanks!  I had to modify my markup to have a FlowPanel directly under the FocusPanel that wraps the label and image, since FlowPanel is a SimplePanel and can only have one widget.  Other than that, worked like a charm.  My only beef is that it produces a bit of extra, unnecessary markup which I'm not a fan of, but I'm quickly realizing that people don't seem to care about that in the GWT world.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't done this before, but you could do the following:

- Create a custom class `MyPanel` that extends `HTMLPanel` and implements `HasClickHandlers`
- Add the following method in `MyPanel.java`

```java
    public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler) {
        return addDomHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());
    }
```

- Then replace `HTMLPanel` with `MyPanel` in your ui.xml and its corresponding Java implementation.

You can always look at the implementation of [`HTMLTable`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLTable.java#719) to get an understanding of how the event propagation works. It's a `Panel` and implements `HasClickHandlers`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the @UiHandler annotation to register event handlers for your custom widget, you need to re-implement the addXXHandler methods. The GWT compiler doesn't seem to find those in superclasses. e.g. if you want to use

```
@UiHandler("myCustomWidget")
public void handleWidgetSelectionChangeEvent(final SelectionEvent<CountryDts> event) {
...
}
```

and your CustomWidget extends a class for which this is working, you might need to add the HasSelectionHandlers interface explicitly to your class:

```
public class CustomComboBox<D> extends ComboBox<D> implements HasSelectionHandlers<D> {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("pmd.UselessOverridingMethod")
    public HandlerRegistration addSelectionHandler(final SelectionHandler<D> handler) {
        // GWT Compile doesn't recognize method in supertype for UIHandler
        return super.addSelectionHandler(handler);
    }
...
}
```